# How do i separate javacscript functions in django templates

Tags: javascript, python, django, file, static

am working with the django 2.1 framework i have a problem with the html template am using, which has several pages like home,about,contacts,and support and each has java scripts functions to automate things in the page like sliders which are at the end of each page before the  
So i decided to have my base.html to contain the footer and header for both pages since are similar .so the problem here is where do i put these js functions 
1. leaving them in the particular page and extending the base.html they don't function
2.attaching them to base.html some properties of the functions don't work too.
any advice please

Comment: Can you include more information such as the code that you've tried and what explicitly works and doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Speaking generally, as this question was asked generally, if I have any shared JS shared between all my templates I place that JS in base.html.  If I write functions specific to a specific page and/or if I want functions called in a distinct ways per page, I place those in a `{% block js %}` block.

Example **base.html**:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sharedFunction() {
        //Do something
    }
</script>

{% block js %}
{% endblock %}
...
```

And **somepage.html**:

```
...
{% block js %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.querySelector("#page-element").onclick = sharedFunction()
    </script>
{% endblock %}
...
```

Hope this helps!